# A-Frame grey border around transparent png image

Tags: png, border, transparency, aframe

A-Frame is adding grey border around the opaque part of png image. Unable to figure out why this is happening. I would be glad to know if anyone has solved this issue.

Comment: Please include code, images, and (ideally) a demo so that others can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some artifacts may happen if you won't set the `material`s property `transparency` to `true`:

```
material="transparent:true; src:myImage.png"
```

check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/86n0Lemz/)

---

Here it's an issue with the image.
Link to your image [here](http://schneewind.decke-wand-boden.de/images/Panorama09-2.png).
I've cut out a guy, check out the legs:[image: guy]

Comment: Her ist my Problem : http://schneewind.decke-wand-boden.de/VRTEST6.html

Comment: Its the same Problem with :  

<a-entity>
     <a-sky material="src:#pano00; rotation: 0 -130 0; transparent:true"></a-sky>
</a-entity>

<a-entity>
     <a-sky material="src:#pano01; rotation: 0 -130 0; transparent:false"></a-sky>
</a-entity>

Comment: Seems this was answered but additionally adjusting the alphaTest property of the material component can help when this happens 

<a-entity material="alphaTest:0.7; transparent:true"> 

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/material.md